# The phase and group velocity in plasma when calculating optical path difference

Tags: optics, astrophysics, plasma-physics, phase-velocity

I know that in plasma, phase velocity $v_{p}$ is faster than light and group velocity $v_{g}$ is slower than light, for the refractive index of plasma $n<1$. When calculating optical path difference, we have $$OPL=\int_{L}n ds$$
therefore the OPD of plasma and vacuum $$\Delta l=\int_{L}n ds -L$$
which means $\Delta l<0$. However, it should be: $\Delta l>0$. The explaination can only be:
$$OPL=\int_{L}\frac{ds}{v_{g}}=\int_{L}n_{g} ds$$ instead of $$OPL=\int_{L}\frac{ds}{v_{p}}=\int_{L}n ds$$
Q1: Why we should use group velocity here? I mean, for example, when considering interference, we consider phase difference, so why not phase velocity?
Q2: I found that in plasma, $n_{g} n=1$, that is to say, $v_{g} v_{p}=c^{2}$. How can I get this equation?